# catch disjonction case exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have 2 classes:

```
class MyException extends Exception implements ExceptionManager{
    MyException addMessage(String message){...}
}
```

and

```
class MyRuntimeException extends RuntimeException implements ExceptionManager {
    MyRuntimeException addMessage(String message){...}
}
```

where

```
interface ExceptionManager{
    ExceptionManager addMessage(String message);
}
```

I want to do this:

```
void foo() throws MyException {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (MyException | MyRuntimeException e){
        throw e.addMessage(...);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work ; I tried setting ExceptionManager<T extends Exception & ExceptionManager> and T addMessage(String message); or other things but still doesn't work...

Obviously I don't want foo to throw Exception nor set 2 catches and the project is java 11 so no scealed types.

Can't the compiler understand that there's only 2 possibilities for the exception to be thrown, one runtime so I only must declare the other ? Can someone tell me how to do or confirm that it's impossible ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by *doesn't work*? Add compilation error(s) if you get any.

Comment: `addMessage` returns an instance of `ExceptionManager`. But an `ExceptionManager` is **not** a Throwable

Comment: It tells me that the exception thrown is not declared in the method.

Comment: Yes I understand but what should I do ?